Nice old example on SDL2 render-to-texture, window doesn’t appear, what changed?
Seeking to understand how to use SDL2 in the  render-to-texture mode, I found this nice, crisp example from the answer to this question and tried it. It builds, it executes without reporting any error and runs for 8 seconds as specified, but no window appears. Changing the position to SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED doesn’t make a difference.
Has something changed in SDL2 in 10 years that would invalidate this example?  Or are there special issues on Mac?
Running on Mac OS 14.2.1 on an Apple silicon computer, with a recently downloaded SDL2. Here is the precise code I'm running:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

// Compile: gcc test.c -I/usr/local/include/SDL2 -L/usr/local/lib -lSDL2


void putPixel(SDL_Renderer *renderer, int x, int y)
{
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255,255,255,255);
    SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, x, y);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int width = 640;
    int height = 480;

    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Test", 0,0,width,height, 0);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_TARGETTEXTURE);
    if (renderer == NULL)
    {
        return -2;
    }

    SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer,SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);

    /* Create texture for display */
    SDL_Texture *display = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET, width, height);

    SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, display);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    for(int x=0;x<8;x++)
    {
        SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, display);

        for(int y=0;y<10;y++)
        {
            putPixel(renderer,40+x*10,50+y);
        }

        SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, NULL);
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, display, NULL, NULL);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        sleep(1);
    }


    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}


Couple things.

Make sure you are calling SDL_Init. Example:

SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);


You should poll for events instead of sleeping the main thread.
You need to call SDL_RenderPresent to render the setup since the previous call. IE:https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_RenderPresent


I found the answer by trial and error: one must handle some initial setup events in order for the window to appear. Whether this represents a subtle shift in SDL2 or a Mac OS issue, I cannot tell, but I rather suspect the latter. I saw this many years ago, on a very different version of Mac OS and using Macintosh native programming libraries. The operating system sends a few events in conjunction with the creation of a window, and until those events are handled, nothing goes right! You don't need to do anything about those events, just quietly swallow them.
Experimentation shows that, in this case, we get 10 events with type 4352, which is undocumented, and then two events of type 512, which refers to the window gaining the input focus (from this answer).
Here's the code that fixed it:
// handle window creation events: A MUST!
while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
}

